# Fishpig - create custom Widget

Tags: magento-2.1, third-party-module, wordpress

Since there seems to be minimal documentation about for Fishpig with Magento 2, please could someone advise a rough process for creating a custom sidebar widget?

Just a basic "Hello world" example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could ask Fishpig to improve their documentation and ask for examples

Comment: @7ochem Believe me, I've tried..

Comment: @wickywills Have you got the answer?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra I can't remember, but I think I contacted the Fishpig developer directly. I don't understand how this question was voted closed as "off-topic" though, since there are MANY open questions about third party modules here.